# Process.waitfor would put service/activity on sleep or it will consume cpu?

Tags: java, android

I have a code which calls `Runtime.exec` which returns a process.
Now if the process is not yet finished reading data from inputstream would not make sense.
So I added a `Process.waitFor`.

Would the calling thread (process/activity method) would sleep ?
Or will it consume cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the calling thread (process/activity method) would sleep ? Or will it consume cpu.

The thread scheduler will suspend the thread calling `Process.waitFor()` until the process exits.

No CPU will be consumed.  (Or to be strictly accurate, no CPU will be consumed by the thread itself.  The scheduler *may* consume a small amount of CPU when it needs to "wake up" the thread, and it is theoretically possible for CPU to be consumed in other ways ... depending on the thread scheduler and OS implementations.)

> Would my activity also be suspended till waitfor returns?

No.  It is just the thread that called `waitFor` that is blocked / "put to sleep".  Assuming your activity has other threads, they will not be directly affected by this.

> Because service and acitvity are part of same android process.

That is not relevant.  It is a single thread that "sleeps" ... not the entire activity or service.

Answer (score 0):

If `waitfor` is properly implemented it should not consume any cycles, as it will use a system call which blocks until the process is done.

Comment: So if I have waitfor in my service. Would my activity also be suspended till waitfor returns ? Because service and acitvity are part of same android process. @CommonsWare Please comment.

Comment: The OS can suspend your process anytime it needs to, so you must be prepared for it anyway.